# Android Espresso: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, kotlin, android-espresso

For an app I am making I have added the following UI test code:

```
@LargeTest
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class MainActivityTest {

    @Rule
    @JvmField
    var mActivityTestRule = ActivityTestRule(MainActivity::class.java)

    @Test
    fun uitest_dialogIsShown() {
        onView(withId(R.id.floatingActionButton)).perform(click())

        onView(withText("Please input an appropriate span count value between 1 and 100:"))
            .inRoot(isDialog())
            .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    }
}
```

Whenever I run UI tests, I get the following exception:

```
2021-11-04 19:47:13.298 6457-6496/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 6457
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~1cBxUPGvZ9-st1nQ3fjOvg==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-VyOwXpNZ2XUs63sLUMZveQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~U_0CC4jTsCAqP3A1qVYV1A==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-Byn_NDW0yN-7_fOcrgQO-w==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~1cBxUPGvZ9-st1nQ3fjOvg==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-VyOwXpNZ2XUs63sLUMZveQ==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~U_0CC4jTsCAqP3A1qVYV1A==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-Byn_NDW0yN-7_fOcrgQO-w==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 19:51:18.309 6775-6798/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 6775
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~9eUxQaX7nbr79YPJlVQsFg==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-xuUtn0i67c_hz-GDuMVQgA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~9eUxQaX7nbr79YPJlVQsFg==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-xuUtn0i67c_hz-GDuMVQgA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 19:55:09.409 6967-7004/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 6967
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~fULPcF44NgcKCpuwKR5lHA==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-H-KHYRNt8ei53g5_34EiXQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~fULPcF44NgcKCpuwKR5lHA==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-H-KHYRNt8ei53g5_34EiXQ==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 19:56:33.028 7133-7158/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 7133
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~U3fFFzguF6B6EP1xeftE0g==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-jPO03IuyhHjn7aSdtUYdpQ==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~U3fFFzguF6B6EP1xeftE0g==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-jPO03IuyhHjn7aSdtUYdpQ==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 19:57:33.922 7259-7312/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 7259
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~5sT64He_bsmo7GYldhR4BQ==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-mXKCT3PwPlIYtUHydiUE8A==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~5sT64He_bsmo7GYldhR4BQ==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-mXKCT3PwPlIYtUHydiUE8A==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:01:22.627 7481-7507/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 7481
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~HYEMhxOJHTO21YfMOmi6bA==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-KLb_D8__Miz7y1IKfSkouw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~HYEMhxOJHTO21YfMOmi6bA==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-KLb_D8__Miz7y1IKfSkouw==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:02:11.479 7605-7654/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 7605
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~A7UND5UmLOPQE0hjOCkaRw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-nyh8mDQAHliAe6L78dXcGg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~A7UND5UmLOPQE0hjOCkaRw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-nyh8mDQAHliAe6L78dXcGg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:02:55.039 7746-7795/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 7746
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~Am2-9l3iwhZVI6IEM8265w==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-EbLdbTKao67SC-ngjoHE7Q==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~Am2-9l3iwhZVI6IEM8265w==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-EbLdbTKao67SC-ngjoHE7Q==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:03:05.232 7909-7935/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 7909
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~YNb6zFX3JmsNu92j87X3wA==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-PLLDtudoh5PbZURWUPctiw==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~YNb6zFX3JmsNu92j87X3wA==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-PLLDtudoh5PbZURWUPctiw==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:05:48.894 8081-8130/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 8081
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~mO79vJVTZ-urkDvSq_HZKw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-3544Ixdu-E3E1jyP5exasA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~mO79vJVTZ-urkDvSq_HZKw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-3544Ixdu-E3E1jyP5exasA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:06:08.849 8207-8259/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 8207
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~aBeMLwXUbOZiJk2DykSYug==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-ksPhMNhyGos-lE5sQwcHzg==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~aBeMLwXUbOZiJk2DykSYug==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-ksPhMNhyGos-lE5sQwcHzg==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:06:20.193 8364-8388/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 8364
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~yo63aoWQGLjkXWlqj5syfw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-vuXZhbEhmMInj4ztj0s-ug==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~yo63aoWQGLjkXWlqj5syfw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-vuXZhbEhmMInj4ztj0s-ug==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:06:46.580 8482-8521/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 8482
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~U2Qrw4_AcDHcRwJ93BT0Wg==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-Ib-zMWEdygJL0xI3M-WgkA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~U2Qrw4_AcDHcRwJ93BT0Wg==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-Ib-zMWEdygJL0xI3M-WgkA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:19:59.251 8759-8803/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 8759
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroidx/test/platform/io/FileTestStorage;
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433)
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "androidx.test.platform.io.FileTestStorage" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/system/framework/android.test.runner.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.mock.jar", zip file "/system/framework/android.test.base.jar", zip file "/data/app/~~K4KgUJ_-JECPlDxPG_Djug==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-XUhqM1pFjOLvLBkELB9LNA==/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~K4KgUJ_-JECPlDxPG_Djug==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose.test-XUhqM1pFjOLvLBkELB9LNA==/lib/x86_64, /data/app/~~OOAovBMGWN3BM4FoM0V0uw==/com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose-ZKeHj2YKiPi9DbleSh6xqQ==/lib/x86_64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:218)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.registerTestStorage(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:636) 
        at androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:433) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:2248) 
2021-11-04 20:30:32.493 9077-9122/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: Instr: androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner
    Process: com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose, PID: 9077
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: ...
```

Unfortunately, I have tried to look at other people's questions who have had the same problem and the solutions offered have not been of help.

Here is my build.gradle file:

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdk 31

    testOptions {
        unitTests.includeAndroidResources = true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.realtomjoney.pyxlmoose"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
    }
    testOptions {
        unitTests.returnDefaultValues = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.1'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha05'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:rules:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'org.robolectric:robolectric:4.4'
    testImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0'
    testImplementation 'org.mockito:mockito-core:3.3.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.1-alpha03'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:truth:1.4.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.google.truth:truth:1.0'
    debugImplementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:runner:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test:rules:1.4.0"
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0"
}
```

I have no idea what's causing this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed this problem by removing the following line in my `build.gradle` file:

```
implementation 'androidx.test:core-ktx:1.4.0'
```

Answer (score 4):

you can solve the problem by adding
`implementation "androidx.test:core:1.4.1-alpha04"`
and changing the version of espresso to `3.5.0-alpha04`
you can understand more from this link
https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/1315

Answer (score 2):

Espresso are not unit tests and you're probably lacking a dependency:

```
testImplementation "androidx.test:monitor:1.4.0"
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer.

Unfortunately I tried to add this dependency, although I am still getting the same error in Logcat.

Comment: @TomJoney It's probably `testImplementation` (else it will bake it into the wrong package).

Comment: What do you mean? I did put in `testImplementation`, or I'm just not understanding your comment? I probably didn't word my comment well 

Comment: @TomJoney this is not a time for joking. One odd thing I see in your `build.gradle` is that you have a bunch of duplicates, such as `androidx.test:runner:1.4.0`. You also are including both the `com.android.support` and `androidx` versions, which might be causing problems.

Answer (score 0):

None of these answers worked for me. What worked was adding this specifically as `debugImplementation` to `build.gradle`.

```
debugImplementation "androidx.test:monitor:1.6.0"
```

Source: [github](https://github.com/android/android-test/issues/1589#issuecomment-1316971699)